# How do I preform a redirect in an angular interceptor?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am pretty new to angular, and I had a question on the best way to handle a redirect within an interceptor.

I have certain pages in my app that I should only be able to access if I have an account selected.  So if an account is not selected I want the route the user to page to select the account.

The following is my failed attempt:

```
    // within config

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $injector){
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                var state = $injector.get('$state');

                if(state.is('user.list')) {
                    var accountService = $injector.get('AccountService');
                    if(!accountService.accountSelected()){
                        
                        // cancel the current request
                        var defer = $q.defer();
                        defer.resolve();
                        config.timeout = defer.promise;

                        state.go('account.select');

                    }
                }

                return config;
            }
        }
    });
```

This is causing an *infinite loop* for me.  For some reason when `state.go` fires -- and it gets re-intercepted the state is still "user.list"

Note: I am using ui-router, angular 1.2.6

Another Note:  The other place I thought of putting this was in a state.resolve block.

Comment: Would a listener for `$stateChangeStart` work for you?

Comment: @zeroflagL -- great comment (+1)  I just tried that -- but still unlucky: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996611/infinite-loop-on-ui-routers-statechangestart

Answer (score 4):

do it like this

```
$injector.get('$state').transitionTo('public.login');
```

full code below

```
var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', '$injector', function($location, $q, $injector) {
    function success(response) {
        return response;
    }

    function error(response) {

        if(response.status === 401) {
            $injector.get('$state').transitionTo('public.login');
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }

    return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
    }
}];

$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

Comment: so I am not sure this approach will work.  I want to intercept the request -- not the response.

also when I use transitionTo vs state.go I get the same behavior

Comment: that was just an example.. you can modify it for request/response... http://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/

Comment: $injector.get('$state') is getting empty in my case, any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

- I think you may want to try $location.path(destination) instead of $state.go(destination).
- You'd better not put your redirect logic under 'request' block as  accountService.accountSelected() may also make a request. here is the [doc of $http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)
- If you only have several routes which need to check account, it is better to put it in state.resolve block as you point out or put it in corresponding controller.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best way to do it or not, but this worked for me when the other answer didn't.